# why angular components do not respect style css?

Tags: css, angularjs, components, angular-meteor

Hello I worked in Free [SB-admin 2](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/) wrapbootstrap with angular 1.5x

I have this:

navigation.html

```
<ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
    <alertas bindinone="navigation.bindinone._id"></alertas>
</ul>
```

alertas.html

```
<li uib-dropdown on-toggle="toggled(open)">
    <a href id="simple-dropdown" uib-dropdown-toggle>
        <i class="fa fa-bell fa-fw"></i>
        <span ng-show="alertas.valueOne  > 0" class="badge progress-bar-danger">
            {{alertasNavegacion.valueOne}}
        </span>
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </a>
</li>
```

all is fine, works fine, but something is ruined the style, I put a next image with the comparation original web and my view

[image]

here with analisis console, inpect element:
[image]

thanks for read!! any ideas please!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hello I found the solution:

CSS must be edited:

before:

```
ul > li > a {
code...
}
```

after:

```
ul > alertas > li > a {
code...
}
```

I dont know how avoid the `ng-isolate-scope in` destroy the style, but I very near.
I hope that this help you.

Thanks for read